# CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND issue using certreq

Tags: azure, ssl

I am attempting to load an SSL cert to my azure environment. I am following the [official Azure documentation instructions located here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/).

When I run `certreq -accept -user ...` it returns back:

> A certificate issued by the certification authority cannot be installed. Contact your administrator. Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)

I am running as administrator.  I am using GoDaddy for my certificate. I converted the crt that godaddy gives you to a cer (export).

I don't see any fixes out there but the standard "pay us and we will fix it for you spy ware"

Steps Taken:

1. I created dns sub domains on go daddy.
2. I then created my cert request following the directions in the link above.
   (create text file and run the certreq -new command against it.
3. I took this file and uploaded the contents to godaddy
4. When godaddy was done authorizing my key I downloaded the IIS version of the key.
5. Unzipped the contents.  Two files were included crt and p7b
6. I installed the certificates on my local machine (I tried with and without this step) in the personal folder.
7. I then exported the crt to cer file.  I noticed that it did say that it was not exporting the keys at the last screen of the export.
8. I then ran the certreq -accept -user command on the cer.  At which point I received the Crypt_E_Not_found error.

Comment: Could you please post all of the steps that you followed. That would help with diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @DanScan: Did you solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @davenewza:  I solved this by loading IIS and creating the crypto file there.  See answer by me below.

Comment: I suggest you mark @Adam Hems answer as correct instead of your own. While yours works of course, I think his is a little easier once you find yourself in that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by loading up IIS from the Windows Feature Activation Services.  I then following the directions for creating a certificate request for IIS.

After creating the certificate request in IIS on my local machine I uploaded it to GoDaddy and followed the rest of the directions as normal.

https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-microsoft-iis-7.htm

Not a good answer but at least it is an answer to get moving.  If I find something better I will post it.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this same error when using the certreq instructions in the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/) and a GoDaddy cert. I fixed it by accepting the request like this:

```
certreq -accept -machine <RandomFilenameFromGoDaddy>.crt
```

I think the problem is that in the [official instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/) the myrequest.txt file has `MachineKeySet = True` in it - I think this needs to be `MachineKeySet = False` (the default) in order to be user-scoped.

Comment: This was the right answer for me. An additional note that might be handy is that you'll need to export the certificate from the machine store and not from the user store. In order to access the machine's certificate store, follow the instructions at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967(v=vs.110).aspx. The certificate will still be found in the "Personal" folder.